# Hyphenation of words connected with a double/triple dash

Tags: hyphenation, babel, shorthands

I can't hyphenate the words

> `Cam•bri•an--Or•do•vi•cian`

because they are connected with an endash. The same probably happens when using the emdash.

I tried this

```
 \defineshorthand{"=}{\penalty1000-\hskip0pt}
 \hyphenation{Cambrian"="=Ordovician}
```

But I obviously don't understand this shorthand thingy.

Comment: the 0pt skip makes a space so Tex sees this as two words and hyphenates each separately, you can't put the compound in `\hyphenation` or define rules for the compound that differ from the two separate words

Answer (score 4):

`\defineshorthand{"|}{\penalty1000--\hskip0pt}` would work in `Cambrian"|Ordovician`, but as David says, not in `\hyphenation`; you have to use the shorthand every time you typeset such a word.

As well, you might actually want to say the following, depending on the typographical traditions of your language:

```
\defineshorthand{"|}{\penalty1000\discretionary{--}{}{--}\penalty10000\hskip0pt}
```

The command `\discretionary` takes 3 arguments and it typesets `#3` if no linebreak occurs at that place, and it typesets `#1<end-of-line>#2` if linebreak occurs at that place.

Complete example showing the different break variants:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\defineshorthand{"|}{\penalty1000\discretionary{--}{}{--}\penalty10000\hskip0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{3.5cm}p{3cm}}
Hellohello Cambrian"|Ordovician World text text text text text text text
&
Hellohello Cambrian"|Ordovician World text text text text text text text
&
Hellohello Cambrian"|Ordovician World text text text text text text text
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. I tried that, and it does hyphenate the word, but also it prints the shorthand: 
`Cambrian”|Or-`
`dovician`
I'm using LuaLaTeX and the fontspec and xunicode packages.

Comment: It _should_ print the hyphen in the place of break of course!

Comment: that's what I meant, it actually prints the "| instead of the endash..

Comment: @PagliaOrba This complete example should help you I hope.

Comment: In the babel package for Cyrillic there is a similar command  "=  for hyphenation which does not work for other language. If you write multi-language documents, it might be more convenient to use "= instead of  "|
So Cambrian"=Ordovician  looks visually better than Cambrian"|Ordovician